# Reading and viewing files in SharePoint using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to develop a proof of concept application that is able to search a SharePoint site for a specific file.

To add to the complexity (for me) I am trying to do this as a UWP app for windows 10 using C# (both are new to me).

I have been browsing the web for the past two days and I am having some difficultly getting started.  Most of the forums I have read state I need to import the following references

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;
```

I cannot import these into my project using visual studio 2017 as they are not listed.

Where should I start?  Am I doing something obviously wrong?  I cant post any code as I am just beginning and having trouble finding information on internet as its all for Sharepoint online (office365).

Further information:  The SharePoint site is on premises (2013).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries for SharePoint are not included in the .NET Framework and must be installed. You can use NuGet for this:

1. In **Solution Explorer** expand your project
2. Right click on **References**
3. Click **Manage NuGet Packages**
4. Make sure **Browse** is selected at the top
5. Search for **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client**
6. Locate the package for **SharePoint 2013**
7. **Install** this package

You should now be able to reference the libraries as you showed in your question.